# Ceiling fan light comes on/stays on - NON remote

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have a Hunter ceiling fan where the light "magically" comes on -- the pull switch has no effect. If I take the 3 screws out and drop the light fixture, the light goes out. (sounds like ground?) I futz with the wires and put it back together which makes it behave for a couple months then, voila! It comes back on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a chafed/exposed wire that is shorting out intermittently due to vibration from the fan motor; either that, or the pull switch itself is failing intermittently.  If you can get it apart and replace the pull switch (Hunter should be happy to sell you the appropriate spare part if you have the model number of your fan handy), try that, and also inspect the wiring closely for bared/chafed spots -- suitable appliance wire for replacing damaged wires should be available at your local hardware or big-box store.